# CodeIgniter project localhost to live server transfer

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I want to transfer my CI project from localhost to a live server, so I copied all my project folders of CI to the `public_html` folder using FTP Client.

I modified the `config.php base_url file`, `routes.php default_controller`, `.htaccess directory` too. But nothing's working.

public_html dir tree:
[image: public_html dir tree]

`.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://xxxxxxxx.com/';
```

The `Others` directory contains my css/js/img files, and all are invoked using `base_url()`, so I don't think that's a problem

The `.htaccess` file in the `public_html` folder is hidden; I don't know why, but when I did a search, it was found here.

Comment: What did you change in routes.php (there is no need for make that change while moving files to live server)?

Comment: @Tpojka I meant, make sure that my default_controller was the one I worked with. Changed nothing just said it was Ok. Just in case if anyone ask about that!

Comment: In `.htaccess` you need value for `RewriteBase` i.e. if it is in root of server, and I suppose it is because of folder name `public_html`,    `RewriteBase /`

Comment: @Tpojka Just tried `RewriteBase / ` and refreshed my site. 404 not found !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files starting with . are considered hidden in the Unix world. If you change your ftp program option to show hidden files, you should be able to see it.

Comment: Thanks for the info bro, didn't know it :)

Comment: Please mark it as answer if you found it to be helpful!

Comment: Lack of reputation point, so I'm unable to do that. Sorry bro ! :( 
I'll mark it for sure when I get enough points, you'll see :D

Comment: how did you solve the problem? I'm facing this problem now. What to do with the ftp program option?